# First-order differential equation non-separable nonlinear

Tags: differential

I know how to solve first-order differential equation that is separable. But I cannot find any way to solve a non-separable equation of this form:

$$\dot{h}(t) +a h(t) =g\left(b(t)h(t)\right)$$

Is it possible to solve it or there is no solution for that?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: There is a third possibility, namely, that there is a solution but there is no finite procedure guaranteed to find it. That is the case with most differential equations, solutions exist but one can only use numerical means to find approximate solutions.